# How to prevent api call when Cancel button is clicked in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a recursion function, I want to stop calling the function when I click the cancel button .
this is submit method:

```js
const submitButton = () => {
    service(convertArray, (status, result) => {
        if (result?.success && submitData) {
            setStatusResult(true);
            if (j < fileData?.chunkResult.length) {
                method(j + 1, percent + percent1);
            }
        } else {
            setStatusResult(false);
        }
    });
};
```

What should I do for the cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions have a base case, use can create a base case and run the function if the base case is not met yet, something like this:

```
const [isCancelled, setIsCanceled] = useState(false);

const onCancelButtonClick = () => setIsCanceled(true);

const submitButton = () => {
  if (isCancelled) return;
  service(convertArray, (status, result) => {
    if (result?.success && submitData) {
      setStatusResult(true);
      if (j < fileData?.chunkResult.length) {
        method(j + 1, percent + percent1);
      }
    } else {
      setStatusResult(false);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: When the submit button is called isCancelled is false, it has no effect when we press cancel